# How do I make sbt include non-Java sources to published artifact?

Tags: scala, sbt

How do I make sbt include non-Java sources to published artifact ?

I'm using Kotlin plugin and can't figure out how to force sbt to include .kt file into published source jar. It only includes .java files.

A lot of people online suggest adding following code to sbt script but it doesn't help

```
mappings in (Compile, packageSrc) ++= {
  val base  = (sourceManaged  in Compile).value
  val files = (managedSources in Compile).value
  files.map { f => (f, f.relativeTo(base).get.getPath) }
},
```

I also tried

```
includeFilter in (Compile, packageSrc) := "*.scala" || "*.java" || "*.kt",
```

Here is output of some variables in sbt console

```
sbt:collections> show unmanagedSourceDirectories
[info] * /home/expert/work/sideprojects/unoexperto/extensions-collections/src/main/scala
[info] * /home/expert/work/sideprojects/unoexperto/extensions-collections/src/main/java
[info] * /home/expert/work/sideprojects/unoexperto/extensions-collections/src/main/kotlin

sbt:collections> show unmanagedSources
[info] * /home/expert/work/sideprojects/unoexperto/extensions-collections/src/main/java/com/walkmind/extensions/collections/TestSomething.java
```

Comment: I couldn't figure that out either - seems a bug in SBT, that only filters *.scala and *.java files (was maybe done before the Kotlin hype;). For example *.scala files in `src/main/kotlin` works

Answer (score 0):

which plugin you use for kotlin?

https://github.com/pfn/kotlin-plugin has the option `kotlinSource` to configure where the source directory is located.

`sbt packageBin` compiled kotlin files and include them to output jar.

build.sbt

```scala
// define kotlin source directory
kotlinSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src/main/kotlin",
```

src/main/kotlin/org.test

```
package org.test

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

console

```sh
sbt compile
sbt packageBin
```

target/scala-2.13

jar include MainKt.class

and folder org/test contains MainKt.class too.

would this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this in my project https://github.com/makiftutuncu/e. I made following: https://github.com/makiftutuncu/e/blob/master/project/Settings.scala#L105

Basically, I added following setting in SBT to properly generate sources artifact:

```
// Include Kotlin files in sources
packageConfiguration in Compile := {
  val old = (packageConfiguration in Compile in packageSrc).value
  val newSources = (sourceDirectories in Compile).value.flatMap(_ ** "*.kt" get)

  new Package.Configuration(
    old.sources ++ newSources.map(f => f -> f.getName),
    old.jar,
    old.options
  )
}
```

For the documentation artifact, I added Gradle build to my Kotlin module. I set it up as shown here https://github.com/makiftutuncu/e/blob/master/e-kotlin/build.gradle.kts. This way, I make Gradle build generate the Dokka documentation. And finally, added following setting in SBT to run Gradle while building docs:

```
// Delegate doc generation to Gradle and Dokka
doc in Compile := {
  import sys.process._
  Process(Seq("./gradlew", "dokkaJavadoc"), baseDirectory.value).!
  target.value / "api"
}
```

I admit, this is a lot of work just to get 2 artifacts but it did the trick for me.  Hope this helps.